# Use this hint to show that any decimal expansion which is eventually periodic

Tags: real-analysis, decimal-expansion

An infinite decimal $x = a_0.a_1a_2 ...$ is eventually periodic if there are positive integers $n$ and $k$
such that $a_{i+k} = a_i$ for all $i > n$.
Show that any decimal expansion which is eventually periodic represents a rational number.
HINT: Compute $10^{n+k}x−10^{n}x$.

I don't know how use this hint.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a power of ten as shifting the digits. For example, consider the decimal $7.8333333\ldots$. Here, taking $n = 2$ and $k = 1$ demonstrates that this is an eventually periodic decimal. $10^{2+1}x - 10^2x = 783.333\ldots - 78.333\ldots = 705$. Now, the interesting thing is that $705$ is an integer! So we have that $1000x - 100x = 705$. But $1000x - 100x = 900x$. So $900x = 705$, so $x = \frac{705}{900}$ and is therefore rational.

This happened because, magically, $10^{2+1}x-10^2x$ turned out to be a whole number. Was that a random coincidence? Or will it happen every time? (hint, hint).

As a general rule, when given a hint like this, try it out on a specific example, and see if you can spot how it's useful *in that one case*. Don't worry about the general case until you can do it for one specific number. Then see if you can prove that whatever tricks you used for that case *always* work.